# openFrameworks with ofxPd: can't modify Pd patch

Tags: android, openframeworks, puredata

I have built an Android application that uses ofxPd to interface with Pd. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/thisisjl/exampleTweenPd).

At the moment, I am loading a pd file called "noisepanning.pd", I load it in the [ofApp.cpp](https://github.com/thisisjl/exampleTweenPd/blob/master/src/ofApp.cpp) source code file. The problem arises when I try to modify it, because the app behaviour does not change, it is like I have not done anything. Moreover, when I try to load another Pd patch, the Android app does not sound at all.

I am not building again with Xcode when I perform these changes, since I am only interested in the Android application. I only use the commands to build the app:

```
make AndroidDebug
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Is there something more I should do when I change the Pd patch?